# IOError: No files found based on the file pattern

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to run the examples found in the Python SDK. However, this errors out with the stacktrace as follows. Note: The first pipeline does create the "./names" file, but the second pipeline does not seem to be able to read from it.

```
No handlers could be found for logger "oauth2client.contrib.multistore_file"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 17, in <module>
    | 'save' >> beam.io.WriteToText(greetings_file))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/io/textio.py", line 391, in __init__
    skip_header_lines=skip_header_lines)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/io/textio.py", line 88, in __init__
    validate=validate)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/io/filebasedsource.py", line 97, in __init__
    self._validate()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/io/filebasedsource.py", line 173, in _validate
    'No files found based on the file pattern %s' % self._pattern)
IOError: No files found based on the file pattern ./names
```

The sample code is below:

```
import apache_beam as beam
def add_greeting(name, messages):
    for msg in messages:
        yield '%s %s' % (msg, name)

names_file = './names'
greetings_file = './greetings'

p = beam.Pipeline('DirectRunner')
(p | 'add names' >> beam.Create(['Ann', 'Joe'])
   | 'save' >> beam.io.WriteToText(names_file))
p.run()

(p
 | 'load names' >> beam.io.ReadFromText(names_file)
 | 'add greetings' >> beam.FlatMap(add_greetings, ['Hello', 'Hola'])
 | 'save' >> beam.io.WriteToText(greetings_file))
p.run()
```

Environment: I'm running this on a google cloud shell

```
$ pip list --local --format=columns | grep dataflow
google-cloud-dataflow              0.6.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a pipeline runs, the runners in Beam don't wait for it to finish, so you should add a call to `wait_until_finish()` after calling `p.run()`.

Also, Beam pipelines have *deferred execution*, so when you define new steps for your pipeline, they are added to a graph that is executed fully every time you run your pipeline. This means, in short, that you need to create a new `Pipeline` object if you want a pipeline that runs different steps.

This should work:

```
p = beam.Pipeline('DirectRunner')
(p | 'add names' >> beam.Create(['Ann', 'Joe'])
   | 'save' >> beam.io.WriteToText('./names'))
p.run().wait_until_finish()

p = beam.Pipeline('DirectRunner')
(p
 | 'load names' >> beam.io.ReadFromText('./names*')
 | 'add greetings' >> beam.FlatMap(add_greeting, ['Hello', 'Hola'])
 | 'save' >> beam.io.WriteToText(greetings_file))
p.run().wait_until_finish()
```

Comment: I still get the same error. The only difference is that I'm running this on my laptop. Are there some debug settings that I can turn on to see if I can get additional information?. The "names" file gets created though. It seems like the second part of the pipeline is still unable to find the previously created file

Comment: Oops. The names file contains a shard number, right? So you'd need to `ReadFromText('./names*')` to be sure. I edited the answer.

Comment: Yes, the filename did contain a shard number.  Adding a "*" at the end worked successfully! Thank you for all your help.

Comment: No problem. If the answer was helpful, you can accept it ; ).